# Need to refine results of logarithmic regression

Tags: regression

Using a logarithmic regression tool found at xuru.org ( http://www.xuru.org/rt/LnR.asp#CopyPaste ) and the data from below, the curve of the graph for this data is roughly described by y = 31.78303295ln(x) - 36.17569359, which has an RSS value of 10877.59526.  My goal is to find an equation that describes the data accurately enough so that I can then multiply it by some smallish constant and the resulting y value will *always* be above, yet still reasonably close to, the expected y value.

As it is, the errors for the calculated y values stray (+ or -) from the actual value in a roughly sinusoidal manner. The errors for the data below are as follows:

```
expected       Calculated         Error
0            -37.0769275         37.0769275 
1            -14.88358987        15.88358987
7            -1.901319596        8.901319596 
8             20.29201803        12.29201803 
16            25.22764812        9.227648123 
19            33.27428831        14.27428831 
20            55.46762593        35.46762593 
23            65.98574081        42.98574081 
111           68.44989621        42.55010379 
112           90.64323384        21.35676616 
113          100.2959388         14.70406121 
118          109.3971665         8.602833487 
121          118.5256062         2.474393843 
124          127.5499778         3.549977828 
127          137.1795899         10.17958994 
130          146.9062597         16.9062597 
143          148.3072802         5.307280243 
144          170.2548897         26.25488974 
170          172.8139194         2.813919413 
178          179.674946          1.674946009 
181          188.876822          7.876821965 
182          209.6750859         27.67508586 
208          212.9576731         4.957673121 
216          218.3963188         2.396318798 
237          226.0826215         10.91737846 
261          242.3657911         18.63420891 
267          260.7888986         6.211101379 
275          266.8441652         8.155834795 
278          276.0074897         1.992510289 
281          285.2181035         4.218103464 
307          289.1736918         17.8263082 
310          297.2291502         12.77084978
```

Bearing in mind that I know very little about statistics, my questions are:

Why is it that when I add more data points the RSS value becomes worse?  e.g. the next data point following "34239 310" is "35655 323". When added to the set below and regression is done on the updated set, I get y = 32.38336295 ln(x) - 38.48210346 with RSS=11417.26182.

As the value of x increases, the results become increasingly inaccurate (namely, y consistently falls well below the target value). How should I interpret this?

Given that the errors *seem* to fluctuate in a sine-like manner, is there some way to use this knowledge to improve the results of the function?

```
data set:
1,0
2,1
3,7
6,8
7,16
9,19
18,20
25,23
27,111
54,112
73,115
97,118
129,121
171,124
231,127
313,130
327,143
649,144
703,170
871,178
1161,181
2223,182
2463,208
2919,216
3711,237
6171,261
10971,267
13255,275
17647,278
23529,281
26623,307
34239,310
```

*Edit by @PeterEllis - addition of illustrative plot showing the original fit*
[image]

Comment: Maybe some plots instead of raw data?

Comment: "Why is it that when I add more data points the RSS value becomes worse? " I think because the logarithm regression is not a good fit. Imagine adding points from a quadratic to a linear regression. Also, I think you meant "namely, y consistently falls well below the target value"

Comment: @Bogdan yes, I meant y not x. Too bad "y" isn't a six-letter word -- then I could edit the post. :)

Comment: @jnthn It would be great if you could register your account here and on maths -- you'll gain full rights to edit your posts, post comments in your threads and claim reputation. You can do this [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/login) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/login).

Comment: @jnthn (1) Plot your (x,y) data first.  The break will clearly show that no simple equation will do a decent job.  (2) Your calculation of errors is misleading: those are *absolute* errors.  The errors themselves are not sinusoidal.  (3) Use a better fitting tool.  E.g., check out [Eureqa](http://creativemachines.cornell.edu/eureqa).

Answer (score 1):

*Why does RSS increase the more data I add?*
RSS is the sum of the squared residuals. If you add another data point and that point is not perfectly on the line, RSS will go up by the square of the distance of your new datum to the regression line. 
Don't use absolute RSS. Try [$R^2$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination)

---

*Given that the errors seem to fluctuate in a sine-like manner, is there some way to use this knowledge to improve the results of the function?* 
The website you mentioned fits $Y = \alpha \log(x) + \epsilon$.
If you think (and it almost appears so) that the non-squared errors have a sinusoidal structure, you might want to try and fit $Y = \alpha \log(x) + \beta \sin(x) + \epsilon$. 
See if that improves anything. Unfortunately that can't be done from that website. So you should try and get a decent software for it.